# Vue.js серверный рендеринг или пререндеринг

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

В документации к vue, говориться про серверный рендеринг и про пререндеринг(https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin). Подскажите пожалуйста, чем пререндеринг отличается от серверного рендеринга? (в документации просто очень лаконично написано и не понятно, может кто уже использовал....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пререндер - это своего рода закос статического сайта под динамический. Ты запускаешь билд, подбираются все данные компонента (возможно даже асинхронные) и пререндерятся в файл для шустрой загрузки. Время от времени нужно передергивать генератор, чтобы менялся динамический контент.
Если же серверный рендеринг, то рендеринг страницы происходит каждый раз при обращении к этой странице (можно конечно кэш настроить и все в этом духе).

Из вышесказанного ты можешь сделать вывод: серверный рендеринг срабатывает при обращении пользователя к странице, а пререндеринг работает независимо от пользователей, он передергивается вручную или же можно автоматизировать и этот процесс. Надеюсь, я понятно изложил суть.

Comment: Gritsenko, спасибо. Получается если на сайте есть авторизация, и по одному и тому же адресу для разных пользователей должны отдаваться разные страницы (заполненные разными данными этого пользователя), то пререндеринг использовать не получиться, верно?

Comment: В таком кейсе вообще не нужен ни пререндеринг, ни серверный рендеринг. Лучше классический spa, ибо эти подходы используют для адекватной индексации поисковиками, а уже потом по приоритету скорость, простота, легковесность и т.п. Если хочешь отдавать разный контент только авторизованным пользователям, то поисковому боту априори не достучаться до этого контента, зачем его пререндерить или делать серверный рендер :\